# How do I index through a PHP array in Javascript using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I am very new to PHP and Javascript. I would like to use a PHP function in order to fetch database data as an array and be able to use it in Javascript. I am  I have searched online but I haven't come across anything that helps my particular situation. How would I get the array in Javascript and be able to use it like so:

```
var arrayJS = arrayFromPhp;
```

My PHP code is below:

```
<?php
    function fetch(){

        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Southflorida8", "test");
        if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM aircraft")){


            if (!mysqli_query($link, "SET @a:='this will not work'")) {
                    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
            }

            $array = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
            mysqli_free_result($result);


            return json_encode($array);
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['fetch'])){

        echo fetch();
    }
?>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
var array = [];



           $.ajax({
                url: 'server.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: 'fetch',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(array) {alert(array);}
            });
 pubnub.publish({channel:pnChannel, message:{lat:array[0][1] , lng:array[0][2] }});
```

Comment: Where does it fail? Do you get back JSON, does the AJAX request make it to the server?

Comment: I don't know PHP, so I can't help on the question itself, but I believe instead of "index" you mean the term "iterate." One iterates through an array. So searching with that term may return useful answers you could not find previously.

Comment: I think you get JSON in alert...?

Comment: For debug better use `console.log` than `alert`

Comment: Does using console.log write the errors to a file?

Comment: `console.log` write to browser console, in Chrome press `Ctrl+Shift+I`

Comment: @Flower If you are getting `Uncaught ReferenceError` you may not be including the jquery library, are you sure you have that included properly?

Comment: @Rasclatt I believe you are right. I am no longer getting the error once I included it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'server.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'fetch',
        success: function(array) {
             array = JSON.parse(array);
             console.log(array);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT: ** And also update your php code.

Replace `$array = mysqli_fetch_all($result);` with `$array = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: I receive this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at phpconnect.php:65 This line corresponds to "$.ajax({"

Comment: Can you comment out the `array = JSON.parse(array)` line. Then, tell me, what was written in the console?

Comment: Have you added the jquery js?

Comment: Yes, that fixed the previous problem. But I have a new error now: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined. For some reason its not reading the array elements im trying to index

Comment: Have you now comment out the `array = JSON.parse(array)` line? We need to know what it returned.

Comment: yep, if I uncomment I get the same error except it shows: [Array(6), Array(6), Array(6)...

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157334/discussion-between-flower-and-haze).